# Retrieving Reviews using Api's from Multple Applications and Websites

Tags: frameworks, review

How can I utilize Application Programming Interfaces (APIs) to retrieve reviews from various applications and websites, even without possessing an access token or ownership of an application? The reviews are publicly accessible, and my objective is to utilize an API to generate code that specifically extracts the `review_id`. What would be the appropriate approach for achieving this?